# 3-phase PWM inverter

Tags: pwm, inverter, three-phase, single-phase

I'm trying to design a three-phase PWM inverter connected to the same single-phase DBR and ac source while keeping the same load for each phase. I have the one-phase circuit but can't do the three-phase...Can anyone help pls?  The specification of the base case is that the load is constantly consuming 1.5 kW at Vrms = 100 V, f = 30 Hz and the switching frequency is 15 kH .This single-phase AC source is 220 Vrms, 60 Hz.

[image]

Comment: To get third phase just simply add on more hlfbridge of switches (probably mosfets in reality) and the third phase will be on the middle of them. You also need to supply third pwm signal for driving those added switches.

Comment: how do i set the behavior voltage sources for the new switches I implement? comparing Van and carrier

Comment: This simple modulation will not work in 3 phase version. You need to switch phases on/off/floating. Look up on the net at bldc motor waveforms. I can build this tomorrow, but try it Yourself.